# Every C# script is throwing errors on the console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just created an Unity project with a clean installation, also created a C# script and attached to a 3D Game Object (Cube), but when I double-click to open the script it instantly says:

```
Exception thrown while invoking [OnOpenAssetAttribute] method 'Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor:OnOpenAsset (int,int,int)' : InvalidOperationException: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <d465e2b2e5054d2787d6364114c43446>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
UnityEditor.DefaultExternalCodeEditor.OpenProject (System.String path, System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/DefaultExternalCodeEditor.cs:96)
Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor.OnOpenAsset (System.Int32 instanceID, System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/CodeEditor.cs:56)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

and

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at <d465e2b2e5054d2787d6364114c43446>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
UnityEditor.DefaultExternalCodeEditor.OpenProject (System.String path, System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/DefaultExternalCodeEditor.cs:96)
Unity.CodeEditor.CodeEditor.OpenFileAtLineColumn (System.String path, System.Int32 line, System.Int32 column) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/CodeEditor/CodeEditor.cs:31)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

And if I, for example, try to use `Debug.Log` in the script, it says

```
'Debug' does not contain a definition for 'Log'
```

Nothing works.

I've already tried to reopen unity, create another project, install another version (I'm now using the latest 2019.2.0b1) and this always happens, I'm using Visual Studio and the errors are prompted in the Unity console.

Comment: Hello, can you edit your post and show us your C# code? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Unity for Visual Studio Tools extension installed in Visual Studio and Visual Studio selected as your editor in the Unity preferences? I've seen that error when Unity gets confused and doesn't understand I want to use Visual Studio instead of Rider as my editor.

Comment: Hello, regarding my code, it's the default code when you create a script, I think Unity is confused in some way like @RetiredNinja said. I'm new to Unity so I've just installed the Unity Hub and selected to install Visual Studio as well, did nothing more than that. How do I check if I have Visual Studio Tools extension? I think Visual Studio is the default because I just double-click the script icon and VS opens.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it was cause of the editor, it wasn't set to Visual Studio as default, I've changed and it works just fine now. Thank you!

Comment: [This link will show you how to change the default script editor in Unity.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1240640/how-do-i-change-the-default-script-editor.html) What worked for OP worked for me too, changing the default script editor. (replying with this link in an answer instead of a comment because I can't comment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to set Visual Studio as the default editor of Unity, as someone in the comment section said.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct .net frameworks installed? Try and install the latest ones. Its the only thing I can think of if you've already tried reinstall Unity.

Comment: @DiegoVinicius I'm fairly sure it does but like I said, its the only other thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch. Try use Visual Studio 2017 and see if you get the same error. When installing Unity the Visual Studio it suggests is the 2017 version. I imagine they may not yet support VS 2019 fully. As I said, just a hunch, but worth trying.

EDIT: Just realized the "2019" part was likely Unity version, but if not, try the mentioned :-)

Answer (score 0):

I re-select VS code in external tools.
[image]